# Loop count in a current transformer

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, physics, current-transformer

[image]

I was reading [this article](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/current-transformer.html) about current transformers. It says that, the loop count is 1 when the wire is just passing through the core. And there are 2 loops when it is wound for once, and 3 loops for when wound twice. It looks like the loop count is \$n\!\!+\!\!1\$ when there are actually \$n\$ loops.

Why do we state the loop count one more than the actual count? Why is there a single loop when the wire is simply passing through the core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because to actually use the components pictured above, you must build them into a circuit. And that means the two loose ends of wire in the illustration are joined via the rest of the circuit.

This completes the loop in the first illustration - it has one complete loop (or one turn) through the core. Then others have two and three turns.

Comment: But that makes a winding with a HUGE radius. As far as I know, a transformer winding **must be** tightly wound. In this case, most of the magnetic flux will complete its path through the free space. Only a tiny amount of the total flux will travel through the core. I don't understand how that "passing through" wire counts as 1 turn; it must be counted as much less then 1 since it weakly excites the core, or should be neglected at all. Can you please explain this point.

Comment: Good complaint, but I would suggest that you look into [Amperes law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law). You define the circulation of the magnetic field as the sum of currents through the loop. It says \$\oint_\ell H \mathrm{d}\ell= \sum I\$, so if you put the circulation loop through the iron you will have the current of the wire passing through the loop in case one. The tightly wound thing is relevant, but in this case it is of less importance as measurement transformers should be designed for the requested application with everything in mind.

Comment: Suggestion: create one loop throguh the magnetic material and one loop halfway through the iron with the other half around the return conductor. You'll see that the return conductor is not needed in close proximity for a good measurement.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the primary to generate the magnetic field which will induce a current in the secondary, it cannot be open circuited.

Closing the circuit creates a loop through which charge can travel and create the magnetic field, making that loop the first turn of the primary.